# Retrieving the value of a given column index from a SQL Result Set query

Tags: java, sql, jdbc, indexing, resultset

I'm fairly new to programming and I'm having an issue getting a particular value from a SQL query using jdbc. I want to get the value from the last row in the 'session_id' column, I know there are 13 rows (which int 'position' is being initialised to) and I hoped that 'resultSet.getInt(13)' would get the value (which is an int) from the final row of the column.

```
  try {
        String sql = "SELECT session_id FROM log_table ORDER BY session_id DESC";
        stmt = conn.createStatement();
        ResultSet resultSet = stmt.executeQuery(sql);

        while (resultSet.next()) {
            if (resultSet.last()) {
                int position = resultSet.getRow();
                latestSessionID = resultSet.getInt(position);
            }
            System.out.println("Latest session_id : "+latestSessionID);
        }
    } catch (SQLException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

However the code returns the following exception

```
Connected to driver     // my own trace
Connected to database      // my own trace
  java.sql.SQLException: Column Index out of range, 13 > 1. 
  at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:1094)
  at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:997)
  at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:983)
  at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:928)
  at com.mysql.jdbc.ResultSetImpl.checkColumnBounds(ResultSetImpl.java:826)
  at com.mysql.jdbc.ResultSetImpl.getInt(ResultSetImpl.java:2710)
  at org.Database.JDBC.checkDatabase(JDBC.java:113)
  at org.Database.JDBC.main(JDBC.java:166)
```

I have tried all the usual options and no question previously asked on stack overflow could answer this problem. Does anyone know the best way to approach this? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you are getting the last record as the latest session id, I assume that your order by condition should be `ORDER BY SESSION_ID ASC` rather than `ORDER BY SESSION_ID DESC`
Use as below:

```
       String sql = "SELECT session_id FROM log_table ORDER BY session_id asc"; 

       int position = 0;    // Number of nth Position

        while (resultSet.next()) {

        if (resultSet.last()) 
        {
            position = resultSet.getRow();
            latestSessionID = resultSet.getInt(1);
            //
            latestSessionID = resultSet.getInt("SESSION_ID");
            System.out.println("Number of sessions = " + position + ", Session ID is : " + latestSessionID);
        }
```

Notes:

- `resultSet.getInt(ColumnIndex)` takes the columnIndex starting from 1, where the first field of query is 1, 2nd field is 2 and so on.....
- Since you want only 1 record, you can also change your query as below:

  ```
  -- For Oracle
  SELECT SESSION_ID FROM LOG_TABLE WHERE ROWNUM=1 ORDER BY SESSION_ID DESC;  

  -- For other DBs based on DB,
  SELECT TOP 1 SESSION_ID FROM LOG_TABLE ORDER BY SESSION_ID DESC;
  SELECT SESSION_ID FROM LOG_TABLE ORDER BY SESSION_ID DESC LIMIT 1;
  ```

Comment: Ahh I was getting to the last column and then trying to search for a column 13 entries down. Stupid mistake! Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Your query only returns one column, session_id. To grab the first column, index with 1.

```
resultSet.getInt(1);
```

You may have been confused because your query returned many *columns*. Columns and rows do not share an index.

- The first column will always be index 1, regardless of what row you are "pointed at".
- The row will always be whatever row you are "pointing at" currently.

If you have ever used a Scanner in Java, you may have encountered similar "pointed at" verbiage before. Basically, the ResultSet "keeps track" of what row you are on. Any methods you call are performed on that row until you finally move the row forward.

For more information, I suggest you read the [Javadoc for ResultSet](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/ResultSet.html).

Answer (score 0):

Your `resultset` will contain one column, being that your query `SELECT session_id FROM log_table ORDER BY session_id DESC` contains one column.

Since the column you're expecting is in the query, then it can be called via either the column name or the index position that it is in, within the `resultset`.

To get your `session_id` from this queried `resultset`, use `resultSet.getInt(1)` or `resultSet.getInt("session_id")`

Here is your altered code, also note the finally block. When using core JDBC, you need to ensure that the JDBC objects are closed, or you'll risk memory leaks.

```
 ResultSet resultSet = null;
 try {
    String sql = "SELECT session_id FROM log_table ORDER BY session_id DESC";
    stmt = conn.createStatement();
    resultSet = stmt.executeQuery(sql);

    while (resultSet.next()) {
        if (resultSet.last()) {
            latestSessionID = resultSet.getInt("session_id");
        }
        System.out.println("Latest session_id : "+latestSessionID);
    }
} catch (SQLException e) {
    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
    e.printStackTrace();
}
finally{
    try {resultSet.close();} catch(Exception e) { } //Suppress Exception
    try {conn.close();} catch(Exception e) { }
    try {stmt.close();} catch(Exception e) { }
}
```

Comment: I see that now, rookie mistake, thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

with this line `latestSessionID = resultSet.getInt(position);` you are trying to call column 13, because the last row is 13. What you need to do is to try to get column 1, since your query: `SELECT session_id FROM log_table ORDER BY session_id DESC` only brings one column to the party.

You could also check this link which explains step by step everything: http://tutorials.jenkov.com/jdbc/resultset.html